# ImageResizer puts a red pixel on images?

Tags: imageresizer

I'm using `ImageResizer` on my website.
Since I update it to `4.0.4` version, it puts a red pixel on bottom right of each image.
You can see it here:
[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: I found it,
In new version of `ImageResizer` there is a license, we have to add it to `web.config`, I don't know how we can set license for an open source project? !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Everything in ImageResizer v4 is now published under an OSI-approved open-source license. Everything that was free in v3 is now [Apache 2 licensed](https://imageresizing.net/licenses/apache) in v4. Everything that was paid in v3 can be used in v4 under the terms of the [AGPL v3](https://imageresizing.net/licenses/agpl). The AGPL v3 typically requires your entire web app to be open sourced. We continue to offer a wide range of commercial licenses for those who do not wish to comply with the terms of the AGPLv3. Commercial licenses include [domain-specific](https://imageresizing.net/licenses/domain), [enterprise-wide](https://imageresizing.net/licenses/enterprise), [OEM redistributable, SaaS resale](https://imageresizing.net/licenses/oem), [development shop redistributable](https://imageresizing.net/licenses/enterprise), and [trial licenses](https://imageresizing.net/licenses/trial).
2. If license key validation fails, a red dot will appear on your images, but nothing will "stop working". You can still use premium plugins for development and testing without a purchase.
3. After checkout, you can verify your license key works by [adding it to Web.config](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install/license_keys) and visiting the ImageResizer diagnostics page `/resizer.debug`. It should explain which functionality your license includes. License key validation is done offline using public-key cryptography; it does not use the network.
4. You can access DRM-free nuget pacakges, source, and binaries if you have an Elite, OEM or SaaS license or a support contract.
5. None of our licenses prohibit removal of the DRM. Removing the DRM doesn't free you from copyright law and the license terms (whether AGPL or commercial), it just means you won't be reminded to comply with them. It's also our tricky way to get you hooked on editing the source code (and, hopefully, sending us pull requests on GitHub).

We implemented license keys based on customer feedback, and clearly announced our intention to do so in 2012. Current rates of piracy have made it extremely difficult to maintain the product and ensure it has a sustainable future.