# ImageResizer Generate a license key

Tags: imageresizer

I have purchased several licenses back in December 2013. Now, I have upgraded the ImageResizer and need to generate a key that I can use in my web.config. Previously I was using drm files and everything worked as it should.
**How do I generate this key or is there any alternative?**

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer v3 was the latest release in December 2013; in 2016 you're likely using ImageResizer v4. You license was valid for ImageResizer 3.X only; you would need to purchase a new license for ImageResizer v4.

See [ImageResizer puts a red pixel on images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852166/imageresizer-puts-a-red-pixel-on-images/33884887#33884887)